# multi-booting Linux distros in the same partition

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

When I install a linux distribution, I allot the disk space to be used during the installation. I could only use up to the allotment. When I am running out of disk space I have to manually shrink one or more partitions and  merge the free space to that partition. Merging it to one partition would make the free space ... free for all installed linux distros. I was thinking of utilizing more of the space. Is it possible to merge them to one partition and configure grub and the distros to boot ?

**EDIT:**
I simplified my wall to a bricks of text by removing some reasons.
By searching in the web, I found a nifty way of booting off just the live cd of the specified distro from grub so I just could test it there all though some functions are not available in the live session.

**EDIT2:**
I may have been overacting with the phrase : `many partitions`. Currently. I have six partitions (including windows's partition because it is part of my hardisk).

Comment: You don't need that many partitions. Every Linux distro can be installed in exactly 1 partition, plus the swap partition which can however be shared. Also, if you wish to test so many distros, you will be much better off by running them off a VM, inside VirtualBox

Comment: I just realize that now and before I sleep nine hours ago. By the way @MariusMatutiae, I quickly rewrite the question. @MariusMatutiae, I may have been overacting with the phrase : `many partitions`. Currently, I have six partitions.